# How to cartoonize images using GPUImage framework?

Tags: swift, image-processing, gpuimage, imagefilter

I'm trying to create cartoon effect by combining multiple filters from ***GPUImage framework*** but the result is not as desired. Already I read all questions that about cartoonizing or cartoonify images but all them old and actually there is no answer with code example. So someone can help me with this topic if it's posible.

My code looks like :

```
var picture:PictureInput!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Filtering image for display
    picture = PictureInput(image:UIImage(named:"girlFace.png")!)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.doFilter()
    }
}

private func doFilter() {
    // to soften
    let sharp = UnsharpMask()
    sharp.blurRadiusInPixels = 30
    sharp.intensity = 8

    // to give oil paint look
    let kuwahara = KuwaharaFilter()
    kuwahara.radius = 6

    picture --> sharp --> kuwahara --> renderView
    picture.processImage()
}
```

[image: And here is the result] but I want something like or near to [image: this image]

All answers, ideas acceptable.

Comment: Do you have a source for your image below?

Comment: Please check it right now.I updated the links

Comment: Do you also have the original source for your second image?

Comment: Both of them linked there

Comment: Has anyone got any particular example, solution, or demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Coder ACJHP understanding your question,

First thing is why don't you use ToonFilter and after that apply KuwaharaFilter, it might work.
But Seeing your final image output, I'm sure that this can be done using AI and coreMl Models.

For your output you can see this link - https://blog.prismalabs.ai/diy-prisma-app-with-coreml-6b4994cc99e1

For coreml models use this link - https://likedan.github.io/Awesome-CoreML-Models/

here you can directly download the models and use it.
Hope this is helpfull

Comment: You know I don't have enough information about Image processing this is my first try

Comment: Your answer is what I'm looking for 

Comment: do read the process carefully of prismalabs blog, it took me while to get it :p, meanwhile you can download the project , which is available at the end of the blog    and download the coreml models from second link, do this iff you are in hurry, otherwise I would recommend to read the blog properly, happy coding :p

Comment: Has anyone got any particular example, solution, or demo?